# Importing svg/Dxf files to trimesh

Tags: python, svg, dxf, trimesh

I want to convert dxf/svg files to stl using trimesh.
I installed cyassimp as indicated on Github page, however I stil lget the following error:

```
 File "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\trimesh\io\load.py", line 119, in load_mesh
    kwargs.update(mesh_loaders[file_type](file_obj,
KeyError: 'svg'
```

Is there an alternative library for file conversation from dxf/svg to STL or to PLY?

Comment: Having the same issue with 'dxf' and `load_mesh()`. Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

trimesh actually has native loaders (doesn't rely on cyassimp) for DXF/SVG. It is probably not available because you don't have shapely or rtree installed. Try calling `trimesh.load_path()` which should print a traceback saying why path functionality isn't available.